# Developer story profile shows "StackOverflow.Models.User+TopTagPercentile" instead of the actual tags

Tags: bug, developer-story

https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/395857 shows some `StackOverflow.Models.User+TopTagPercentile` instead of the actual tags:

[image]

Why?